# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'devolucionItems') and possible issue with .map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm pretty new to javascript, and I'm trying to get the information from an order return to appear on the DeliveryReturnScreen.js page. This page is accessed by pressing a button/handler in my OrderHistoryScreen.js. My issue is that the DeliveryReturnScreen is blank and I can't get my information to show up. I'm not sure if I have setup my .map() correctly, but in my console I'm receiving a TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'devolucionItems') error. I'm unsure of why I'm receiving this issue as my devolucionItems and all of the return information are shown in my mongodb once the button is pressed. i would really appreciate any help or advice on how to resolve this issue.
Thank you!

Note: devolucion is the variable name that I used for my returns

DeliveryReturnScreen.js

```
export default function DeliveryReturnScreen(props) {
  const navigate =  useNavigate();
  const params = useParams();
  const {id: devolucionId} = params;
 
  const devolucionDetails = useSelector((state) => state.devolucionDetails);
  const {devolucion, loading, error } = devolucionDetails;
  const userSignin = useSelector((state) => state.userSignin);
  const { userInfo } = userSignin;
  
      return (
        <div className="row top">
        <div className="col-2">
           (
            <MessageBox>
              
            </MessageBox>
          ) : (
            <ul>
              {devolucion.devolucionItems.map((item) => (
                <li key={item.product}>
                 
                    
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          )}
        </div>
        <div className="col-1">
          <div className="card card-body">
            <ul>
        
              
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

OrderHistoryScreen.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { listOrderMine, detailsOrder } from '../actions/orderActions';
import {useNavigate, useParams} from 'react-router-dom';
import LoadingBox from '../components/LoadingBox';
import MessageBox from '../components/MessageBox';
import {createDevolucion } from '../actions/devolucionActions';
import { DEVOLUCION_CREATE_RESET } from '../constants/devolucionConstants';

export default function OrderHistoryScreen(props) {
  const navigate =  useNavigate();
  const params = useParams();
  const {id: orderId} = params;
  const order = useSelector((state) => state.order);
  const devolucionCreate = useSelector((state) => state.devolucionCreate);
  const { success, devolucion } = devolucionCreate;
 
  const orderMineList = useSelector((state) => state.orderMineList);
  const { loading, error, orders } = orderMineList;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listOrderMine());
   // dispatch(detailsOrder(orderId));
  }, [dispatch,
     //orderId
    ]);

  const placeDevolucionHandler = (id) => {
    
    const selectedOrder = orders.find(order=>order._id === id)
    dispatch(createDevolucion({ ...selectedOrder, devolucionItems: selectedOrder.orderItems }));
    
  };
 
  useEffect(() => {
    if (success) {
      navigate(`/devolucion/${devolucion._id}`);
      dispatch({ type: DEVOLUCION_CREATE_RESET });
    }
  }, [dispatch, devolucion, navigate, success]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Order History</h1>
      {loading ? (
        <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>
      ) : error ? (
        <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>
      ) : (
        <table className="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {orders.map((order) => (
              <tr key={order._id}>
                <td>{order._id}</td>
                <td>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  onClick={()=>placeDevolucionHandler(order._id)}
                  className="small"
                >
                  Return
                </button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

initial state is probably null and it can't read it from so you need to check if the value is null

use optional chaining

`devolucion?.devolucionItems?.map`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining